# Proper way to download image from server using headers

Tags: php, http-headers

I made a script which creates .jpg file and saves it to server, then I want to make it downloadable by user but when I open this image which I downloaded I get error about corrupted file, although this image is not corrupted because I can open it from server (manually with image viewer). These are my headers:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg");
readfile('image.jpg');
```

I also tried to change Content-type to image/jpeg but I get same results

Comment: save the file, open it with a text editor, anything funny in the top?

Comment: I don't know what's funny in the top, but I got this: ??JFIF,,?? ICC_PROFILE mntrRGB XYZ acspAPPL?? desc?|cprtx(wtptﾠbkptﾴrXYZ?gXYZ?bXYZ?rTRC

Comment: looks ok, sometimes you get a php error message inside the file top, which breaks it.

Comment: Search for PHP **warning**,**notice**,... inside your image file!

Comment: Hmm, when I opened it with different text editor on top I found my html code and then some weird code, I suppose that's my image. But everything is ok with image on my server, something is wrong with headers

Comment: I found the error. Thing is, I had some output before sending headers, which is wrong, so I seperated my code into two files, output commands in one file and header commands in other, now everything works. Thank you